# How to customize Emacs vc-annotate command in Git

Tags: git, emacs

I find Emacs standard `vc-annotate` command very useful used together with Git.

However in command line Git I can run `git blame -w` to ignore whitespace changes. By default this switch is not used in Emacs.

How can I configure Emacs to ignore whitespace changes when running `vc-annotate`?

Comment: While the `git blame` output isn't exactly the same, I recommend [Magit](//magit.vc/) for using Git in Emacs. Magit *does* have the ability to add the `-w` flag to `git blame`.

Comment: Also, while this question is not necessarily off-topic here, you may have better luck asking on [Emacs.se]. Please note that [cross posting is generally frowned upon](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), so if you decide to seek help there instead, you should either (1) post a new question there and delete this one, or (2) flag your question for a [moderator to migrate](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/269535).

Comment: Thank for the tips about emacs.stackexchange.com. I found a solution to this in: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/how-to-change-options-passed-to-git-vc-annotate/27348#27348

Comment: Feel free to post that solution as an answer here for reference (linking to the original to give credit, of course).